# Make DOM elements appear fixed in place without a computed style of 'fixed'?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, css-position

We all know that modern web browsing is extremely painful. See this screenshot of the BBC's website for example:

[image]

On some screens, the actual content here wouldn't even make the first page. It gets even worse when you add fixed footers with advertisements or "We've updated our Terms of Service" messages. And don't even mention overlays.  On any given day, one has to dismiss, accept, or reject hundreds of generic web messages, or be consigned to reading their web content from within a narrow field of view that is a fraction the height of their screen.

Fortunately, being a tech savvy web user, I am aware that browser extensions exist that can hide all fixed-elements on any given page and I make liberal use of these both on desktop and mobile. ([Here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-fixed-elements/) is the one I use, but there are many others.)

This may work by the mere chance that they are uncommon. If, for example, *everyone started using them* then surely all the folks that put those headers and footers there in the first place would be really annoyed and find a way to work around them. This could be the reason why you don't see any browsers adopting this as a built-in functionality, despite the problem (and solution!) being around for years.

As a backend engineer I don't have a lot of experience in frontend to answer this myself. But one of the original propagators of this technique is [Alisdair McDiarmid's post](https://alisdair.mcdiarmid.org/kill-sticky-headers/) from 2013 where he explains how it works based on this snippet:

```
(function () { 
  var i, elements = document.querySelectorAll('body *');

  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (getComputedStyle(elements[i]).position === 'fixed') {
      elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
    }
  }
})();
```

This checks whether the final computed style of any element is `'fixed'`, and if so it just removes it from the DOM entirely. This *seems* pretty foolproof to me but then again the last decade has shown that, given incentive, web developers have found nearly infinite ways around user's desire to block content via CSS ad filters for example.

Can you make DOM elements appear fixed in place on the screen without them getting a computed style of 'fixed'?

Comment: This question is off-topic, but boy, do you get my support concerning all these exasperating cookies, terms of service, location authorisation, notifications requests and messages. And that's even before seeing the actual content and all the ads. On every. single. website. you. visit.

Comment: In the end isn't it essentially an HTML/Javascript question? Can you reimplement all the sticky header, footer, etc stuff without having an element get a computed style of `'fixed'`? My question does include other context outside of that, but it's more to inform the core question itself. I wondered about off-topic, so I looked at other SE sites first and couldn't find one that seemed more appropriate for the question than StackOverflow itself.

Comment: Your question is about "Is it possible to implement something..." so it's an open question, also maybe opinion-based, so my guess is, it's probably off-topic. I don't have the answer though, and I didn't vote to close.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've made it more specific and, I believe, eliminated the open-endedness of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Plenty of ways. You just need to control which element gets scrolled. Here's a simple way with Flexbox.

```css
h1 {
  background-color:magenta;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
}
body { 
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100vh;
  margin:0;
}
main {
  overflow:auto;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My non-scrolling, non-fixed heading</h1>
  <main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was sorely tempted to make the text blink too, for maximum irritation factor. I settled for just a magenta background.

Comment: lol, \*sigh\* I guess this means I should not expect a bright future of being able to hide fixed elements everywhere.